# Unable to serialize a HashMap

Tags: java, android, serialization

I'm trying to *Serialize* a `HashMap`, but it's throwing `NotSerializableException`

I'm declaring the `HashMap` as:

```
HashMap<String, Profile> profiles = new HashMap<String, Profile>();
```

Here's my code:

```
ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(openFileOutput(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
objectOutput.writeObject(profiles);
objectOutput.flush()
```

*Profile.java*

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Profile implements Serializable {
    String name;
    String server;
    int port;
    boolean useSSL;
    boolean autoConnect;
    String nick;
    String alterNick;
    String realname;
    String username;
    String serverPass;
    String nickservPass;
    String[] autojoinChannels;
    String[] connectCommands;
}
```

The elements are initialized like this:

```
Profile profile = new Profile() {{
    name = "SOMETHING";
    useSSL = false;
    // etc. etc.
}};
```

*Logcat:*

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: tk.microdroid.microirc.MainActivity
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
        at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1013)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1053)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
        at tk.microdroid.microirc.MainActivity.saveObject(MainActivity.java:168)
        at tk.microdroid.microirc.MainActivity.saveDefaultProfiles(MainActivity.java:201)
        at tk.microdroid.microirc.MainActivity.checkFirstStartup(MainActivity.java:70)
        at tk.microdroid.microirc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
        at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

**EDIT**

- `Profile` class is defined in a separate file, not an inner class
- Here are the saveObject() and loadObject() methods

  ```
  public Object loadObject(String name) {
      try {
          ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(openFileInput(name));
          Object obj = objectInput.readObject();
          objectInput.close();
          Log.v("loadObject()", "Loading " + name + ".. | Type: " + obj.getClass().getName());
          return obj;
      } catch (Exception e) { Log.e("loadObject()", e.toString()); }
      return null;
  }

  public void saveObject(Object obj, String name) {
      try {
          Log.v("saveObject()", "Saving " + name + ".. | Type: " + obj.getClass().getName());
          ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(openFileOutput(name, MODE_PRIVATE));
          objectOutput.writeObject(obj);
          objectOutput.flush();
          objectOutput.close();
      } catch (Exception e) { Log.e("saveObject()","Error", e); }
  }
  ```

Comment: how do you write the HashMap ?

Comment: @Blackbelt through objectOutput#writeObject(profiles) and then I flush the stream

Comment: I would really like to know why this question has been downvoted, I just don't get it

Comment: can you use `e.printStackTrace()` and post the complete stacktrace. It looks good,

Comment: can you post the method saveObject ?

Comment: Are you sure that Profile isn't an inner class of `MainActivity`? If so, it needs to be declared `static`. Otherwise I don't see a reason why the serialization framework would be trying to serialize `MainActivity`. Try posting more code from MainActivity... including saveObject

Comment: @Barett it is probably the case, because the stacktrace is poisoning out that MainActivity can't be written

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally, I was able to fix my issue

I was setting object variables as:

```
Profile profile = new Profile() {{
    name = "SOMETHING";
    useSSL = false;
    // etc. etc.
}};
```

So I just tried to set the variables without using double brackets, like:

```
profile.name = " SOMETHING";
profile.useSSL = false;
// etc. etc.
```

I'm not even sure why that caused the problem but finally I have fixed it.

Comment: It caused the problem by creating an inner class, which has a reference to the enclosing object, which wasn't Serializable.

Comment: Using the double brackets is essentially an anonymous inner-subclass of Profile, i.e profile is no longer strictly of type Profile. Also because it is a non-static inner class it therefore has a reference to its enclosing object, and this was not serializable.

Comment: Yeah, this pattern of instantiation is generally an anti-pattern; you should avoid it. I've seen it a few places as a "neat trick," and you should generally regard it as just that: a neat trick, not suitable for real code (where tricky code tends to cause tricky bugs).

Answer (score 3):

If Profile is an nested class of MainActivity, declare it as static. (Besides this, I don't see a reason why the serialization framework would be trying to serialize MainActivity.) If that's not the case, please post more code from MainActivity, including saveObject, and we will update the answers.

Non-static nested classes have an implicit reference to their container class. So the serialization framework will try to serialize your MainActivity.

Comment: 'Non-static inner' is a tautology.